# Byte incrementing operation in Java

Tags: java

What happens when we try to increment a byte variable using the increment operator and also by the addition operator.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        byte b = 1;

        b++;

        b = b + 1;
    }
}
```

Please give me the source where we can find such small things unleashed? Please help me out.

Comment: `What happens... ` Why don't you try it out?

Comment: "Please give me the source where we can find such small things unleashed" - The Java Tutorial, any good Java text book ... or if you are good at reading formal documents, the Java Language Specification

Comment: Unless you use `b` you won't see anything happen.

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. Why? The 3rd statement will in fact not compile. Cannot cast form an `int` to a `byte`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The difference** is that there is an `implicit casting` in the `++` operator from `int` to `byte`, whereas, you would have to do that `explicitly` in case if you use `b = b + 1`

```
b = b + 1;  // Will not compile. Cannot cast from int to byte
```

You need an explicit cast:

```
b = (byte) (b + 1);
```

Whereas `b++` will work fine. The `++` operator automatically casts the value `b + 1`, which is an `int` to a `byte`.

---

This is clearly listed in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) - [§15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) : -

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once

---

Please note that operation `b + 1` will give you a result of type `int`. So, that's why you need an explicit cast in your second assignment.

Comment: But when I use an int it still shows me error???

Comment: Sorry Rohit.....When i use the explicit cast that u've said, still gives me error.

Comment: @Praveen.. It should not give error AFAIK. Can you please post your current code?

Comment: public class A3{ 
public static void main(String str[]){ 
byte b=1; 
b++; //line 2 
System.out.println(b);
b=(byte)b+1; //line 3
System.out.println(b); 
}}

Comment: So what happens if I write b = b + (byte)1? Just Curious!!!

Comment: @Praveen.. Note the bracket. `(byte)b + 1` should be `(byte)(b + 1)`

Comment: @Vishal.. That would also not work. Because, even though you converted `1` to a byte value, the result of operation between two byte values is an `int`. And then again the same reason.

Comment: NO it is not compiling Vishal

Comment: Yeah. That would not compile, as per the reason I posted in my last to last comment.

Comment: @RohitJain I'l compile it and see now

Comment: @RohitJain Now I am little confuse... Anyway I will try to find it later. Thanks

Comment: @RohitJain Hurrah thanx............It s working

Comment: @Vishal.. Actually, the type of the result you get of an expression is at least an `int`. Now, as you add a higher type, the type of result is that higher type. Operation between: - `byte and byte is int`, `int and byte is int`, `int and long is long`, and so on.,

Comment: @RohitJain where do u find these smaller things....Give me some tips to do good programming???

Comment: @Praveen.. All comes from experience my bro. Don't worry much if you don't know about them now. Everyday you keep on adding new stuffs to your knowledge bag, and thus learning many things. Just Enjoy Coding, and forget everything :)

Comment: @RohitJain it is an information to me... Hope I could remember it.. Thanks.

Comment: Yep bro...Thnx for ur help. Can i get ur mail id?

Comment: @RohitJain Can i get ur mail id?

Comment: @Praveen.. That's in my profile information. And You're welcome :)

Comment: @RohitJain Thank u bro...Keep Sharing

Comment: @Praveen.. Sure. You can anytime mail me whenever you have any problem. Else, SO is always there. Be in touch with SO to learn better programming, and yes, Enjoy Coding. :)

Answer (score 3):

What happens? Actually `b = b + 1` won't compile.

You must explicitly convert it to `byte`, because `b + 1` evaluates to `int`. And it is not guaranteed that an `int` can fit into a `byte`.

`b = (byte)(b + 1);`

Comment: Well, b = b + 1 will not compile.

Comment: Why is it happening so Rohit?

Comment: @Praveen.. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be incremented twice

Answer (score 0):

b++; and b=b+1; are equivalent and will result in the same bytecode.

b will be equal to 3 before the main method is finished.

Edit: actually they are not equivalent: b=b+1; is wrong and should be b=(byte) (b+1); [cast to a byte, otherwise it is an int]

Comment: But when I execute the code I'm getting a compile time error???