# unable to increment byte value with expression but with increment operator

Tags: java, byte

why 
 the following is valid

```
byte i=0;
i++;
```

where as the following is invalid

```
byte i=0;
i=i+1;
```

what would be the reason?

I know in the case of `i+1` the entire value is explicitly incremented by 1 (which will be `int` value) so compilation problem will occur, but in case of `i++` it does the same but did not get any error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13452664/2006839 already there in so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you perform a binary operation between two operands of different types, one of the operands is promoted to the higher type. And then the result of the operation is of that type.

So, in your case, the `byte` type a is first promoted to an `int`, since `1` is an `int` type. And then after the addition operation, the result is of type `int`. Now, since you cannot assign an `int` to a `byte`, you need to do a typecast to remove the compiler error:

```
byte a = 2;
a = a + 1;   // Error: Cannot assign an int value to byte
a = (byte)(a + 1);  // OK
```

Now, in case of Compound Assignment Operator, the typecasting is done implicitly for you. The expression:

```
a += 1
```

is internally converted to:

```
a = (byte)(a + 1);
```

This is specified in JLS - [§15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operator:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

`A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.`

Similar is the case with prefix increment operators, and postfix increment operators.

According to JLS - [§15.15 Unary Operators:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)

`The type of the prefix increment expression is the type of the variable.`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing out JLSs @rachana

Answer (score 0):

add/subtract/multiply etc.. these operations are done by converting the operands in RHS to integers... So here, you are trying to reassign the integer (RHS value generated after completion of operation) to a byte... BOOM. "CANNOT CONVERT FROM INT TO BYTE" - ERROR says it all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you say `i = i + 1`, `i` is of type `byte` and `1` is of type `int` in java. The result of `i` + `1` is therefore an `int`. Assigning it to a `byte` causes loss of precision.

Comment: I know that. My question is about doesnt i++ work as i+1

Comment: No. `++` is aware of the type of the variable it is operating on and acts accordingly. It is same with `+=`. You don't get any error for `i+=1` either.

Comment: @MaheshVarma - automatic(implicit) casting back to its original type is done in i++.